# SQL: get all variation points for a continuous value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a sensor value which is sampled quite frequently, so that the value stays the same for more than one sample, i.e.:

```
Date        Value
2010-01-01  1.345
2010-01-02  1.345
2010-01-03  1.555
2010-01-04  1.555
2010-01-05  1.555
2010-01-06  1.345
2010-01-07  1.752
2010-01-08  1.752
```

And would like to get just the lines in which the value varied:

```
Date        Value
2010-01-01  1.345
2010-01-03  1.555
2010-01-06  1.345
2010-01-07  1.752
```

One option would be to use a LAG window function to get the previous row for each row (ordering by date) and comparing current/previous, but I'm wondering if there is a pure SQL solution.
I solved the problem with a self outer join as

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.value
FROM table t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2
ON t1.value = t2.value
AND t1.date > t2.date
WHERE t2.date IS NULL;
```

but this works only **if there are no duplicate values**, like it's the case here for value 1.345

I must add that unfortunately the Date values are unique, but not equally spaced in general.

I'm currently working with a PostgreSQL database, but I believe the question can be adapted to any system.

Comment: Can you ensure a consecutive index on the table? Or can the date be trusted as one?

Comment: Try the self outer join on t2.Date = t1.Date + 1 and WHERE t1.Value<>t2.Value

Comment: @AlinPurcaru Dates are unique, but irregularly spaced in general

Comment: Is a trigger a possibility to prevent the insertion of no duplicate values, or do you want a query that avoids them in general?

Comment: I'm not the owner of the original data, so I must make with what I get

Comment: Why does using the `lag()` function not qualify as "*pure SQL*"?

Comment: Well, I know it's standard SQL now, but first of all LAG() is not widely implemented and I was wondering how you would do without. Second, these functions break the declarative SQL language to add some procedural traits, and so they don't benefit for example from the query optimizer, indices etc

Answer (score 1):

By using rank and linking to previous days data and display only when last day is not equal to next day.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([Date] DATE, Value DECIMAL(18,10))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2010-01-01',  1.345),
('2010-01-02',  1.345),
('2010-01-03',  1.555),
('2010-01-04',  1.555),
('2010-01-05',  1.555),
('2010-01-06',  1.345),
('2010-01-07',  1.752),
('2010-01-08',  1.752)

SELECT 
    pDATA.[DATE],
    pDATA.[VALUE] 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        T2.[DATE],
        T2.VALUE , 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY T2.[DATE]) - 1 AS R2 
    FROM @T AS T2) AS pDATA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        T1.[DATE],
        T1.VALUE , 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE]
    ) AS R FROM @T AS T1) AS DATA

    ON DATA.R = pDATA.R2
WHERE 
    DATA.Value != pDATA.Value 
    OR DATA.Value IS NULL
```

Comment: This will give you the greatest date in each group, not the first. For example, you'll see January 2nd instead of January 1st for 1.345.

Comment: You need to put the -1 in the first group. I tested this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/95bd9/5), and if you make that change it'll work great.

Comment: Thanks @McAdam331 didn't catch that simple reversal of table order when crafting the answer.  Reposted the change. THX

Comment: Good fix, +1 from my end then.

Answer (score 0):

Show all rows, excluding those with values which are the same as the previous rows.

Find the previous row by joining each row to all the ones with a smaller date and finding the maximum date in that group of smaller dates

In SQLIte:

```
SELECT Date, Value, 0 FROM Readings
EXCEPT
SELECT y.Date, y.Value, ABS(y.Value- z.Value) AS Diff
FROM (SELECT a.Date AS au, Max(b.Date) AS bu FROM Readings AS a JOIN Readings AS b ON a.date>b.date  GROUP BY a.date) AS x --
JOIN Readings AS y ON y.Date=x.au --
JOIN Readings AS z ON z.Date=x.bu
WHERE Diff <.001
```